# Rails: Time#to_f precision in JSON?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, floating-point

I'm building a simple JSON API using Rails 3.2.1 and [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) on Ruby 1.8.7 (1.9.x might help me here, but my hosting provider only has 1.8.7).

Since the API consumer expects timestamps as floats, I'm currently just doing a simple `to_f` on the time attributes:

```
json.updated_at record.updated_at.to_f #=> 1328242368.02242
```

But `to_f` incurs a precision loss. This causes some issues when the client requests records that have been modified since a given point in time, as the SQL query finds the same record that the client uses for reference. I.e. when trying to find "newer" records than the example above, the SQL query (e.g. `updated_at > Time.at(1328242368.02242)`) returns that same record, since the actual value of `updated_at` is more precise and fractionally larger than the given timestamp.

In fact, `record.updated_at.usec #=> 22425` or `0.022425`seconds. Notice the extra decimal.

So optimally, the timestamp should be JSON'ified with 1 extra decimal, e.g. 1328242368.022425, but I can't find a way to make that happen.

```
updated_at.to_i #=> 1328242368       # seconds
updated_at.usec #=> 22425            # microseconds
updated_at.to_f #=> 1328242368.02242 # precision loss

# Hacking around `to_f` doesn't help
decimals = updated_at.usec / 1000000.0 #=> 0.022425         # yay, decimals!
updated_at.to_i + decimals             #=> 1328242368.02242 # dammit!
```

I've looked around for ways to set the default float precision, but I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Edit: I should add that the API consumer isn't running JavaScript, so the float *can* have higher precision. It would break JS-compatibility (and thus the JSON spec) to add another digit (decimal or otherwise), since JS floats can't handle that, I believe. So perhaps I need an entirely different approach...

Comment: Can you output the time as the string: `"#{updated_at.to_i}.#{updated_at.usec}"`? (Well, adding leading zeroes to `usec` as needed.)

Comment: Yes and no. I could do a lot of stuff like that if I was outputting a string. But I need to output a float. And if I make a string, and then run `to_f` on it, I'm back where I started: Precision loss.

Comment: Could you output BigDecimals instead of floats? The JSON library might be able to treat those as numbers.

Comment: Close but no cigar. `BigDecimal` gets JSON'd as a string (though with all the proper precision). And if I `to_f` a `BigDecimal` instance, it once again incurs the precision loss... I may need to find a way to append "raw" JSON, so I can use `BigDecimal` to a get the string, and output it without quotes. Seems hacky though...

Comment: `BigDecimal` being only supported as a `to_s` fallback is worth reporting a bug against the JSON library. It's a number, it should be encoded as one.

Comment: @Inerdial Actually, it's doing the right thing. There's a comment specifically about BigDecimal's JSON-behavior [in the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/BigDecimal.html#method-i-as_json). Long story short: Most JSON parsers (i.e. JavaScript) can't grok big numbers

Comment: I'm not sure that should be the JSON library's call to make, since obviously the JSON parser you're targeting can grok them. The docs do give me an idea: as long as you're not concerned with the problem of Javascript JSON parsers truncating the numbers, you could monkeypatch the JSON library. Replace `BigDecimal#as_json` with an implementation that returns `self`, and add `BigDecimal#encode_json` with one that returns `to_s`, analogously to how they do with [`Numeric`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#LC181).

Comment: @Inerdial That works! And I can monkeypatch `Time` to give me a `BigDecimal`. Ain't as pretty as just `Time#to_f`, but if you post your comment as a proper answer, I can give you a checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the deliberation in the comments, the best option seems to be monkeypatching `ActiveSupport::JSON` to make it handle `BigDecimal`s the same as `Numeric`s:

```
class BigDecimal
  def as_json(options = nil) self end #:nodoc:
  def encode_json(encoder) to_s end #:nodoc:
end
```

This overrides the Rails team's decision to prevent serialised `BigDecimal`s from being parsed as floats (and losing precision) in JSON deserialisers with no support for decimal numbers.